# Select the item in combobox with key/up in WPf

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox

How to select the items in comboxbox using key up/down?

I tried to handle it in PreviewKeyDown event. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard navigation is already present for any control deriving from [Selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.aspx) as the CoboBox does. The control has to have focus before it will capture the key events as well. 
Are you trying to do something other then select/scroll through the items? Because it already does that.

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with the above answer. First you have to select the control.

e.g.

Here is a sample `xaml` code

```
<Page x:Class="CascadingDropDown.Page1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Page1" Loaded="Page_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Height="23" Margin="60,32,120,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" DisplayMemberPath="CountryNames" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In the .CS file add the following

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DataContext = CountryTable();
    comboBox1.Focus();
}

private DataTable CountryTable()
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();

   dt.Columns.Add("CountryNames");

   dt.Rows.Add("India");
   dt.Rows.Add("Australia");
   dt.Rows.Add("Canada");
   dt.Rows.Add("USA");

   return dt;
}
```

So after loading, you will find that the combo is selected. Use the up / down arrow key for the items to be selected.